# a problem when trying to replace parameters in a lua file

Tags: lua, torch

I have never previously worked with lua programming but I have to run a package written in lua language. This package is a command line linux interface and I don't have to know lua programming. In this package I only need to replace some addresses in lua files with my own address and dataset or file names to be able to run the program. But I came across a problem in running a lua file. In this file I replaced the following piece of code:

```
dofile 'Csv.lua'

local proteinFile = Csv(opt.dataset..".node","r")
local proteinString = proteinFile:readall()

ppFeature = {}
pNumber = {}

for i=1, #proteinString do

local fileName = opt.dataset..'/'..proteinString[i][1]

if file_exists( fileName ) then

local proFile = Csv( fileName, 'r', '\t')
local profile = proFile:readall()
```

with this one:

```
dofile 'Csv.lua'

local proteinFile = Csv("/storage/users/ssalmanian/DPPI/myTrain.node","r")
local proteinString = proteinFile:readall()

ppFeature = {}
pNumber = {}

for i=1, #proteinString do

local fileName = '/storage/users/ssalmanian/DPPI/myTrain/proteinString[i][1]'

if file_exists( fileName ) then

local proFile = Csv( fileName, 'r', '\t')
local profile = proFile:readall()
```

and I got error. 
 Necessary input files before running the command include a file and a folder with names the same as the -dataset:

A)The suffix of the file is ‘.node’ (myTrain.node). This file has one column which contains names of all proteins.

B) Profile folder with the same name as -dataset (myTrain). This folder contains profiles of all proteins.

The name of the profiles inside this folder is the same as the protein names in ‘.node’ file.

I was wondering if someone could let me know what's wrong with it and which piece of code must be replaced with the following:

```
local fileName = opt.dataset..'/'..proteinString[i][1]
```

Thanks.

### EDIT:

The package is [DPPI](https://github.com/hashemifar/DPPI) package and I tried to run creat_crop.lua code to create two files myTrain_profile_crop_512.t7 and myTrain_number_crop_512.t7 using the following command in a CUDA server :

```
th creat_crop.lua -dataset myTrain
```

That creat_crop.lua code is dependent in calling Csv.lua code and needs myTrain.node file and myTrain folder. Here I have added my WinSCP page[image: WinSCP page] and the error I get [image: Error message].

Comment: In the original file replace every occurrence of `opt.dataset` with `"/storage/users/ssalmanian/DPPI/myTrain"`

Comment: I had replaced with the same address but what about proteinString[i][1]? Is there anything wrong with it? why do I get error? Should I use any placeholder for this part of file path?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `proteinString[i][1]`

Comment: So local fileName =  '/storage/users/ssalmanian/DPPI/myTrain/proteinString[i][1]' is correct?

Comment: No.  Only `opt.dataset` must be replaced.

Comment: What is the final script which must be replaced with local fileName = opt.dataset..'/'..proteinString[i][1]? I replaced it with local fileName = "/storage/users/ssalmanian/DPPI/myTrain/"..proteinString[i][1] and the next time with local fileName = "/storage/users/ssalmanian/DPPI/myTrain/"proteinString[i][1] and finally with local fileName = "/storage/users/ssalmanian/DPPI/myTrain/proteinString[i][1]" but none of them worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210550/discussion-between-sara-and-egor-skriptunoff).